# R function Comparegroups package

Tags: r

```
library(compareGroups)
res <- descrTable(TenYearCHD~.,data= df,show.p.overall = TRUE,method = "1",sd.type = "2")
res
```

I got the result of the table. How do I use `export2word()` to have it export as a word file?

```
export2word(res, file = tempfile(fileext = ".docx"))
```

This is what I tried but not working. Did not see anything under my working directory.

Comment: Instead of `file = tempfile(fileext = ".docx")` try: `file = "compare.docx"`.

Comment: Thanks but it is not correct.

Comment: `export2word(res, file = "compare.docx")` works on my end.

Comment: Yes, it works. I thought it would be file = tempfile(file = "compare.docx"). Thank you!